# SSIS Derived Column - How to convert substring to date?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using the SSIS Derived Column transformation.  The source of the field is the Filename that's saved in the flat file source.  Thefully-qualified UNC path is

```
\\v201.os33cust.net\TKFMC\groups\Managed Care Operations\Health Plan Specific Data\Self-Funded\MedImpact\Accumulator\Download\Reload\type28_phi01_ais_02032021_02032021_001.txt
```

Since the filename is a UNC path, and I just need the date portion of it in yyyy-mm-dd format, I wrote the following expression in the derived column transformation:

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(Filename,155,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Filename,151,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(Filename,153,2))
```

The initial processing succeeded a few days ago.  Today, an error is thrown stating:

```
An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
```

The destination field for the above expression is in SQL Server 2016 using the date field type.  The reason the date is formatted as yyyy-mm-dd is because the format is needed further downstream when I produce a flat file requiring this format.

Since the process succeeded a few days ago, and nothing has changed with regard to environment, table etc., I'm curious to know how best to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the file names, maybe the format changed so your parsing of the date does not work because the file name format changed.  Also if it stopped today but worked yesterday, maybe your date was only accounting for 1 digit for day (so 2/9/21 yesterday but 2/10/21 today) so extra character you may not have taken into count.

Comment: Please share the fully qualified file path value of the Filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UNC**

```
\\v201.os33cust.net\TKFMC\groups\Managed Care Operations\Health Plan Specific Data\Self-Funded\MedImpact\Accumulator\Download\Reload\type28_phi01_ais_02032021_02032021_001.txt
```

It is very dangerous to rely on the `SUBSTRING()` function while processing UNC paths because they flactuate.
SSIS has much better functions for your scenario:

- `TOKEN()`
- `TOKENCOUNT()`

In the following example, the `TOKEN` function returns the file name from the specified path:

```
TOKEN(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\"))
```

So you will have **type28_phi01_ais_02032021_02032021_001.txt** at this point.

You would need to repeat the same approach while using underscore character to tokenize it. The file name contains 6 tokens. It seems that you need a token #4.

```
TOKEN(TOKEN(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\")), "_", 4)
```

So you will have **02032021** at this point.

And just after that use the `SUBSTRING()` function to compose a DATE.

Here is your full expression:

```
SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\")), "_", 4), 5,4)
+ "-" +
SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\")), "_", 4), 1,2)
+ "-" +
SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::fileNameUNC], "\\")), "_", 4), 3,2)
```

**in VS:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I used the second Token statement in the Derived Column transformation.  Unfortunately, the package fails with the same error as before.  Might there be a different approach?

Comment: IMHO, it is the best approach. If your starting point is a fully qualified path, you need to start where I started in the answer with both functions: `TOKEN()` as well as `TOKENCOUNT()`.

Comment: @SidC, I updated the answer with the full Expression. Check it out.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  The final solution for me was the following expression:(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(Filename,"\\",TOKENCOUNT(Filename,"\\")),"_",4),5,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(Filename,"\\",TOKENCOUNT(Filename,"\\")),"_",4),1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TOKEN(TOKEN(Filename,"\\",TOKENCOUNT(Filename,"\\")),"_",4),3,2))

Comment: @SidC, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you.